# javascript syntax error on basic arithmatic in adobe

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I am just trying to create a basic document level function that takes 2 values and returns the difference.  I keep getting a syntax error on the line that includes (cEnd - cStart) / msPerDay no matter where it is. I've tried creating a new variable `var diff = (cEnd - cStart) / msPerDay;` and I've tried calling cEnd and cStart differently.  I even just tried (x + y) / c, and still got a syntax error.  I thought maybe I needed to declare that cEnd & cStart were variables but that also didn't work.  I thought maybe I called the if statement wrong but that also looks right so I'm not sure what's wrong with this:

```
function fDays(cEnd, cStart){
  /* 24 h/d * 60 m/h * 60 s/m * 1000 ms/s) */
  var msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

  if (cEnd == null || cStart == null) {
    return 0;
  else {
    return (cEnd - cStart) / msPerDay;
  }
}
```

Comment: You forget to close If .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in if / else syntax, the syntax should be like this:

```
if (cEnd == null || cStart == null) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return (cEnd - cStart) / msPerDay;
}
```

So the whole code will be :

```
function fDays(cEnd, cStart){
        /* 24 h/d * 60 m/h * 60 s/m * 1000 ms/s) */
        var msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    if (cEnd == null || cStart == null) {
        return 0;
        }else {
            return (cEnd - cStart) / msPerDay;
        }

    }
```

Comment: ah thanks.... I didn't think I needed to close before the else.  I feel silly now.